# Are night and day lengths over a year equal everywhere on earth?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

As you all know, in winter the nights are longer and there is nearly no sun, but in the summer there are really long days.

If you look at different places over the world, you find strange things like a 3 month day in summer with 3 months of darkness in the winter when you keep going north or south enough.

The question I asked myself was:

**Question: Is the overall length of day equal to the overall length of night over the time span of one year (thus half of the year for both) everywhere on earth?**

I tried to solve this analytically, but looking at complex trigonometric function that include the earth rotating around its tilted axis around sun lead to nowhere.

However, I noticed that when looking at mountains / high buildings, the overall day length becomes longer, thus this question is meant for a **spherical earth with no altitude differences**.

Comment: This is probably for physics.se unless you have a model

Comment: One idea could be to look at this empirically provided you can find data on the lengths of days and nights from different regions around the world.

Comment: How far poleward are you? Because the tropics and a good fraction of the temperate zones don't have "nearly no sun" in winter.

Answer (score 2):

The earth's orbit is elliptical, with the sun at one focus.  It spends more time on one side of the sun than the other.
I think the Northern summer is longer than the Southern summer, by a few days.  Ask the Physics Stackexchange.